# Merge the first words in a list of word-pairs, depending on the second words in those pairs

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, grouping

I have a program (NLTK-NER) which provides me with this list:

```
[
    ('Barak', 'PERSON'),
    ('Obama', 'PERSON'),
    ('is', 'O'),
    ('the', 'O'),
    ('president', 'O'),
    ('of', 'O'),
    ('United', 'LOCATION'),
    ('States', 'LOCATION'),
    ('of', 'LOCATION'),
    ('America', 'LOCATION')
]
```

As you can see "Barak" and "Obama" are words of type "PERSON", and I want to merge them (and words of type "LOCATION") together, like this:

```
['Barak Obama','is','the','president', 'of','United States of America']
```

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we're looking to do here, essentially, is group some items of `classified_text` together … so it stands to reason that [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can help. First of all, we need a key function that treats items with the tags `'PERSON'` or `'LOCATION'` as similar, and all other items as distinct.

This is slightly complicated by the fact that we need a way to distinguish adjacent items that have the same tag (other than `'PERSON'` or `'LOCATION'`), e.g. `('is', 'O'), ('the', 'O')` etc. We can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for that:

```
>>> list(enumerate(classified_text))
[..., (2, ('is', 'O')), (3, ('the', 'O')), (4, ('president', 'O')), ...]
```

Now that we know what we're going to provide as input to `groupby()`, we can write our key function:

```
def person_or_location(item):
    index, (word, tag) = item
    if tag in {'PERSON', 'LOCATION'}:
        return tag
    else:
        return index
```

Notice that the structure of `index, (word, tag)` in the assignment matches the structure of each item in our enumerated list.

Once we've got that, we can write another function to do the actual merging:

```
from itertools import groupby

def merge(tagged_text):
    enumerated_text = enumerate(tagged_text)
    grouped_text = groupby(enumerated_text, person_or_location)
    return [
        ' '.join(word for index, (word, tag) in group)
        for key, group in grouped_text
    ]
```

Here it is in action:

```
>>> merge(classified_text)
['Barak Obama', 'is', 'the', 'president', 'of', 'United States of America']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the first thing it came to my mind, pretty sure it could be optimised but is a good start.

```
    classified_text = [('Barak', 'PERSON'), ('Obama', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('president', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('United', 'LOCATION'), ('States', 'LOCATION'), ('of', 'LOCATION'), ('America', 'LOCATION')]

    # Reverse the list so it pops the first element
    classified_text.reverse()
    # Create an aux list to store the result and add the first item
    new_text = [classified_text.pop(), ]
    # Iterate over the text
    while classified_text:
        old_word = new_text[-1]
        new_word = classified_text.pop()

        # If previous word has same type, merge. 
        # Avoid merging 'O' types
        if old_word[1] == new_word[1] and new_word[1] != 'O':
            new_text[-1] = (
                ' '.join((old_word[0], new_word[0])),
                new_word[1],
            )

        # If not just add the tuple
        else:
            new_text.append(new_word)

    # Remove the types from the list and you have your result
    new_text = [x[0] for x in new_text]
```